# Software to display a website for a trade show or something similar

Tags: web-browser

I need a recommendation for a software that can display a website without the addressbar. The computer/tablet should not respond to keyboard input and the application should not be closable. It shouldn't be possible to leave the domain that is configured. It's this kind of software that you see in some retail stores or a trade show.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: The keyword is "kiosk". Look for [kiosk](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=kiosk) software

Comment: thank you! I think that was what i was looking for. I would like to mark your anser as correct but unfortunatly it is only a comment.

Comment: That's no problem, we are here to help :-) If I had had more time, I would have posted an answer, but I figured that you can Google just as well as I can, and you will know better what suits you. Btw, if you were to post an answer ans explain why you chose it, that would help others who read this question in future.  It is encouraged to so, and to accept your answer. Welcome aboard, and I am glad to have been of help

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is basically a Digital Signage software.

Check out https://www.digitalsignage.com/

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. But though the software shouldn't react on keyboard input, it should still be usable via touch gestures or mouse input